# Cannot move foo.cs. The destination folder is the same as the source folder

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

My Visual Studio 2017 is awfully liberal in its interpretation of what mouse gestures count as an attempt to move a file. Whenever I try to click on a file, it seems that if I move the mouse at all, even one pixel, VS thinks I am trying to move the file, so I get the popup below.

Is there any way to tell VS not to see a move attempt unless I move the mouse pointer a bit further?

[image: popup]

Comment: I'd have to guess that you haven't used a touch-enabled program before.  Did you configure it?  Use Control Panel > Pen and Touch.

Comment: I can't find any "pen and touch" in the control panel (Windows 10 pro). I disabled my touchscreen a while ago, and also the trackpad.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Windows 10, by default, if you move an item by at least 4 pixels, and drop it it, it will excecute a drag and drop operation. You can modify this threshold to your needs.

The function for changing the drag threshold is [SystemParametersInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947(v=vs.85).aspx).

SystemParametersInfo writes the values into they registry key [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop] as DragHeight and DragWidth.

You can modify the values there.

[image]